# Write multiple authors in a way that fits on one line

Tags: titles

I'm using the Coling2020 template (https://coling2020.org/coling2020.zip).
When i try to add authors (more than 4 authors) it doesn't fit exactly, since the affiliation is a little long.

It shows the authors as follows:
[image]

I want to show them as follows:
[image]

Any idea how to do it?

Code snipet

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{coling2020}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}



%\setlength\titlebox{5cm}
%\colingfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission

% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.


\title{Instructions for COLING-2020 Proceedings}

\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It is done, a minimal working example is added, but still needs to use the official template so it can work

Comment: The format you want doesn't seem to match what the guidelines require. What do you mean by "doesn't fit exactly"? You can increase the size of the titlebox by changing the value in the commented out line in your example document.

Comment: It's clear that the style provided is not well suited for multiple affiliations for a single author, nor very well suited for papers with a large number of authors (since the layout is very space consuming.) So you would need to take that up with the proceedings editors to be allowed to do something else. Independently, because of the way the package works, you can't simply use the `authblk` package to implement the format you're asking for, which is the usual way to achieve such a format.